# Git HTML 5 demo on OSX

Tags: php, macos, html

I am very new to Web development and wanted to run one of the Github project (https://github.com/remy/html5demos) on my Mac.

I have downloaded the project on my Mac and puzzled how to run it. Need help from all talented people across Stackoverflow.

Comment: For opening (and running) PHP files on your MAC you need a Apache with PHP server. OSX Leopard (and newer) have this by default. In this tutorial you can find out how to run it. http://www.editrocket.com/articles/php_apache_mac.html

Answer (score 1):

The demo using php. Unfortunately, the apache installed on OSX (assuming you're on Snow Leopard) has not have php enabled by default and you need some admin-editing to enable it.

So, first move the unpacked folder remy_something into /Library/WebServer/Documents and rename it to easy name, for example "remy". (The final path /Library/WebServer/Documents/remy)

enable Web sharing in System preferences

point your browser to http://localhost/remy/index.php

```
if you get an rendered page - you're done, and can start playing...
if you get an error - something is terrible ;(
if you get a page where is the 1st line <?php - you're on good way - you need enable php.
```

For enabling php in OSX's apache, you should read for example: http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/how-to-setup-apache-and-php-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard or any other guide you can find.

after enabling php and restarting apache (disable/enable Web sharing), you can check again the page...

Comment: Thanks Rich ! This was really helpful. I have Snow Leopard and index.php is able to rendered. But second problem I have is No url found .After clicking on any of the link on index.php it says UR not found. Probably the resource is missing. But I have downloaded and unzip entire folder and it should work.